# Vue 3 in iOS 9: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode

Tags: babeljs, vuejs3

My Vue 3 app doesn't work in Safari 9. There is this error in console:

```
Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.12.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-slider-component": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "sass": "^1.28.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {},
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "safari >= 7",
    "ios_saf >= 8",
    "chrome >= 52"
  ]
}
```

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@vue/babel-preset-app']
  ]
}
```

I know that the error can be caused by not-transpiled dependencies, but I tried to transpile them in vue.config.js by `transpileDependencies` option. But doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

So here's an answer for my question: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6041#issuecomment-722966178

Vue 3 doesn't support iOS 9 yet.